# pg_restore: error: input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

I have a backup of PostgreSQL database (taken from Heroku) now I want to restore this backup to my local database but it's not working. I tried from CMD and pgadmin, but no luck!

What wrong I am doing?

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U nafuser -d naf latest.dump
```

pgadmin issue:

[image: pgadmin issue]

Comment: 1) What is the size of `latest.dump` file? 2) How was the backup of the Postgres database done on Heroku? **Add answers as update to question**.

Comment: Please _always_ include error messages as _text_, not an image.

Comment: It seems like your backup file is empty.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about file size. I checked it and it was of ZERO bytes and I realized that the file is empty. After that, i Regenerated the backup from Heroku and restored it in my local PostgreSQL database and it worked. Thanks :) 
@AdrianKlaver